# Comparing two text files in python

Tags: python

I need to compare two files and redirect the different lines to third file. I know using diff command i can get the difference . But, is there any way of doing it in python ? Any sample code will be helpful

Answer (score 17):

check out [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html)

> This module provides classes and
>   functions for comparing sequences. It
>   can be used for example, for comparing
>   files, and can produce difference
>   information in various formats,
>   including HTML and context and unified
>   diffs[...]

A command-line example in http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib-interface

Answer (score 6):

```
#compare 2 text files.

test1filehandle = open("test1.txt", "r") #creating a file handle
test2filehandle=open("test2.txt","r") #creating a file handle to read
test3filehandle=open("test3.txt","w") #creating a file handle to write
test1list= test1filehandle.readlines() #read the lines and store in the list
test2list=test2filehandle.readlines()
k=1
for i,j in zip(test1list,test2list): #zip is used to iterate the variablea in 2 lists simultaneoously   
    if i !=j:
        test3filehandle.write("Line Number:" +str(k)+' ')
        test3filehandle.write(i.rstrip("\n") + ' '+ j)
    k=int(k)
    k=k+1;
```

Answer (score 4):

> **Comparing two text files in python?**

Sure, [difflib](https://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) makes it easy.

Let's set up a demo:

```
f1path = 'file1'
f2path = 'file2'
text1 = '\n'.join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ''])
text2 = '\n'.join(['a', 'ba', 'bb', 'c', 'def', ''])
for path, text in ((f1path, text1), (f2path, text2)):
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)
```

Now to inspect a diff. The lines that use `os` and `time` are merely used to provide a decent timestamp for the last time your files were modified, and are completely optional, and are optional arguments to `difflib.unified_diff`:

```
# optional imports:
import os
import time
# necessary import:
import difflib
```

Now we just open the files, and pass a list of their lines (from `f.readlines`) to `difflib.unified_diff`, and join the list output with an empty string, printing the results:

```
with open(f1path, 'rU') as f1:
    with open(f2path, 'rU') as f2:
        readable_last_modified_time1 = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(f1path)) # not required
        readable_last_modified_time2 = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(f2path)) # not required
        print(''.join(difflib.unified_diff(
          f1.readlines(), f2.readlines(), fromfile=f1path, tofile=f2path, 
          fromfiledate=readable_last_modified_time1, # not required
          tofiledate=readable_last_modified_time2, # not required
          )))
```

which prints:

```
--- file1       Mon Jul 27 08:38:02 2015
+++ file2       Mon Jul 27 08:38:02 2015
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 a
-b
+ba
+bb
 c
-d
+def
```

Again, you can remove all the lines that are declared optional/not required and get the otherwise same results without the timestamp.

> **redirect the different lines to a third file**

instead of printing, open a third file to write the lines:

```
        difftext = ''.join(difflib.unified_diff(
          f1.readlines(), f2.readlines(), fromfile=f1path, tofile=f2path, 
          fromfiledate=readable_last_modified_time1, # not required
          tofiledate=readable_last_modified_time2, # not required
          ))
        with open('diffon1and2', 'w') as diff_file:
            diff_file.write(difftext)
```

and:

```
$ cat diffon1and2
--- file1       Mon Jul 27 11:38:02 2015
+++ file2       Mon Jul 27 11:38:02 2015
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 a
-b
+ba
+bb
 c
-d
+def
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) !=3 :
  print "usage:" + sys.argv[0] + "   bla bla"
  exit
elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
  file1 = set((x for x in open(sys.argv[1])))
  file2 = set((x for x in open(sys.argv[2])))
  file3 = file2.difference(file1)
  file4 = file1.difference(file2)
  str1="file1-contains but  file2 not \n"
  str2="file2-contains but  file1 not\n"
  FILE = open('file3','w')
  FILE.writelines(str2)
  FILE.writelines(file3)
  FILE.writelines(str1)
  FILE.writelines(file4)
```

Comment: Regardless of whether this code works, it doesn't really explain how to do what the question asks.